# Changing python array shape

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array

```
[
 [[R G B]
  [R G B]
  [R G B]]
 [[R G B]
  [R G B]
  [R G B]]
 [[R G B]
  [R G B]
  [R G B]]
]
```

and I want it in the form

```
[
 [[R R R]
  [R R R]
  [R R R]]
 [[G G G]
  [G G G]
  [G G G]]
 [[B B B]
  [B B B]
  [B B B]]
]
```

How?

Comment: Have you tried to get its Transpose? Let's say your array is a, np.array(a).T

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B']],[['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B']],[['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B'],['R', 'G', 'B']]])
 
print(np.transpose(a))
```

Output

```
[[['R' 'R' 'R']
  ['R' 'R' 'R']
  ['R' 'R' 'R']]

 [['G' 'G' 'G']
  ['G' 'G' 'G']
  ['G' 'G' 'G']]

 [['B' 'B' 'B']
  ['B' 'B' 'B']
  ['B' 'B' 'B']]]
```